# CSS. Проблема с background-color

Tags: css

При использовании background-color к блоку  на странице остаются зазоры сбоку. Как исправить и в чем проблема?

Comment: Предоставьте код, чтобы правильный ответ сразу.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего это отступы родительского блока. Если вы пытаетесь добавить фон основной обертке на странице, значит у вас работают дефолтные отступы у body.

Пропишите либо для родителя, либо для всех элементов (*) следующее

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Помогло

Прописал для родительского блока и все сразу заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: отступы выдаются на весь элемент, padding тут игнорируется, да и margin тоже.

Comment: У него проблема была не с блоком, к которому применяется стиль, а с тем, что у родительского блока были отступы. Поэтому визуально казалось, что фон не заливает весь блок.